# 1.7 years experience but I have 1 arrear

Tags: career-development, recruitment, human-resources, india, career-switch

I have been working in datastage for 1.7 years and I have planned to switch to other company due to my salary being an issue. However, I have 1 arrear (backlog) currently, meaning that I have failed an exam and have not been awarded my college degree. Will this create a problem for my career or I can get a job?

Comment: what does arrear mean? Backlog of what?

Comment: You have backlog of work at your current company?

Comment: Indian context, backlog means he has failed in one exam and need to write that exam again to pass the course.

Comment: Hi @Nanda i have a query out of curiosity & not demotivating or belittling you, how did your current employer agree on hiring you while you are having a backlog as I assume you would not have got your degree awarded to you.

Comment: @penta Smaller companies don't care much about the actual degree.

Comment: I'm working in a small scale IT company, they hired me and they know about my backlog too....I thought, I will clear my arrear and wish to try in MNCs. But God plan is changed, so I need to change my current company due to salary rise

Comment: @Nanda I would suggest you to keep attempting to clear your backlog, "you can be wrong a billion times, but you need to be right only once", dont loose hope ! Can I ask which subject was it ?

Comment: Maths 4 - PQT ( probability and queueing theory ) @penta

Comment: I'm need in job with 1.7 years experience in datastage developer role....If any vacancy in your company, please suggest me, it will be a great help from u guys. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Usually MNC's usually won't consider people with arrears, unless with large experience. Its more than ok on smaller companies.

My advice is to take a job in a smaller company, study and pass the arrear and switch to MNCs (if you are interested).

Comment: @Nanda.kumar047 If its all right, please accept the answer.